# Is it correct to simplify the multiple prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

I saw this on news:
"....during a briefing on the opioid epidemic Tuesday at his golf club in New Jersey."

Does it mean "on the opioid epidemic on Tuesday"?

Answer (score 1):

No, the epidemic did not happen on Tuesday. Consider the briefing having been about World War 2, you would immediately assume that war didn't happen on Tuesday.

The briefing
* was about *the opioid epidemic*
* took place *on Tuesday*
* took place *at his golf club*

And the golf club is *in New Jersey*.

Although for the latter part, it actually means the same if you read the meeting happened there or the golf club is there, because they are necessarily in the same place.

Comment: “If they start, it's awfully tough to get off”, he said during a briefing on the opioid epidemic at his golf club in New Jersey.   --- How do I add Tuesday to this sentence correctly?

Comment: How about "....he said, during a briefing on the opioid epidemic, at his New Jersey golf club on Tuesday".

Comment: @Novice You could do it as in your Original sentence, which is effectively not ambiguous at all, or you could move it to the end, as WS2 suggests. Or even _... he said on Tuesday, during a briefing on the opioid epidemic ath his golf club in New Jersey._

Answer (score 0):

Your version implies a one-day epidemic. To some extent the original does too, but less so. Sentences like this (with multiple qualifying phrases) can be awkward and are often better broken down.